# 301 Redirects Subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I´d like to do this:

```
Redirect 301 test/ http://domain.com/test/tester/
```

When I do this I get error message to many redirects.

I need some help.

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 0):

You proberbly have forgot to add a RewriteCond to avoid redirecton loops.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?test/$
RewriteRule /?test/ /test/tester/ [R=301]
```